# interpretação do quicksort

Tags: c, classificação, quicksort

Aprendi Haskell, e agora estou começando a aprender C. Estive tentando passar o meu código do quicksort em Haskell para C mas não obtive sucesso. Então decidi olhar alguns livros e encontrei o seguinte código:

```
/* Função de inicialização da Quicksort. */
void quicksort(char *item, int count)
{
    qs(item, 0, count-1);
}

/* A Quicksort. */
void qs(char *item, int left, int right)
{
    register int i, j;
    char x, y;

    i = left; j = right;
    x = item[(left + right)/2];

do
{
    while(item[i]<x && i<right) i++; // DUVIDA 1
    while(x<item[j] && j>left) j--;  // DUVIDA 1

    if(i<=j)
    {
        y = item[i];
        item[i] = item[j];
        item[j] = y;
        i++; j--;
    }
 }
 while(i<=j); // DUVIDA 2

 if(left<j) qs(item, left, j);
 if(i<right) qs(item,  i, right);
}
```

Duvida 1) Fiz alguns testes de mesa, compilei e executei com algumas entradas e não descobri o porque de colocar `&& i<right` e `&& j>left` dentro do while sendo que o próprio `item[i]<x` e `x<item[j]` já faz as devidas verificações.

Duvida 2) Para este código não seria mais correto colocar apenas `while(i<=j)` ao invés do `do while(i<=j)`.

Comment: Veja o [tour]. Você pode aceitar a resposta que melhor lhe atendeu em cada uma das suas perguntas se achar que resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O quicksort funciona, em pseudo codigo, da seguinte maneira:

```
1) Escolha um elemento do vetor, chamado de pivo.
2) Ordene o vetor de forma que todo elemento menor que o pivo
esteja a esquerda dele e todo elemento maior esteja a direita.
3) Aplique os passos 1 e 2 para os dois "vetores" resultantes, o
de elementos maiores e o de elementos menores.
```

A funcao `quicksort` do seu exemplo e so um wrapper para a funcao
`qs`.

A funcao `qs` e a que faz os passos que eu descrevi acima:

```
i = left; j = right;
x = item[(left + right)/2];
```

`x` e o nosso pivo, nesse caso sempre o elemento que esta na metade do
vetor (nao vou entrar no merito da discussao se esse e um bom pivo ou
nao).

```
    while(item[i]<x && i<right) i++;
    while(x<item[j] && j>left) j--;
```

Agora, o que ele faz e, a partir do inicio do vetor, mas sem passar de
`j`, que marca o fim do vetor, incrementar `i` enquanto  elemento que
esta na posicao `i` for menor que o pivo, e o mesmo para `j`. Logo, ao
final desses dois whiles acima, todos os elementos com indice menor
que `i` sao menores que o pivo e todos os elementos maiores que `j`
sao maiores que o pivo. Ele faz isso porque nao precisamos mexer
nesses elementos, ja que eles respeitam o fato que que os da esquerda
do pivo sao menores que ele e os da direita maiores.

Depois desses dois whiles nos tambem sabemos que o `item[i] > x` e
`item[j] < j`, ou `i >= j`.

Se `i < j`, nos sabemos, entao, que `item[i] > x` e `item[j] <
x`. Logo, nos trocamos ambos de lugar e 'arrumamos' o vetor ate esse
ponto. Em seguida incrementamos `i` e decrementamos `j` para analisar
os proximos elementos.

Quanto a sua duvida 2, o `do...while(i <= j)` e o `while(i <= j)` sao
identicos, ja que dentro do while ele faz a verificacao. Entao foi a
gosto do fregues :P

Nota: Esse codigo deve ser de alguma referencia antiga, ja que ele usa
a palavra `register`, que "nao faz nada".

Outra coisa e que o quicksort em Haskell e bem mais simples, mas esta
fazendo exatamente a mesma coisa:

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
          where
                  lesser  = filter (< p) xs
                  greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

O `p` e o pivo, `lesser` sao todos os elementos da lista menores que
`p` e `greater` os maiores. As chamadas para a funcao `filter` que
deixam o quicksort um tanto melhores.

Comment: Então se eu omitir `&& i<right` e `&& j>left` do while vai dar problema ? O que eu estava com mais dúvida era isso, pois executei sem `&& i<right` e `&& j>left` e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim, vai dar problema. Tente rodar com um vetor ordenado ao contrario, como `5 4 3 2 1`.

Comment: Testei sem `&& i<right` e `&& j>left` utilizando `5 4 3 2 1` como meu vetor e funcionou do mesmo jeito. Eu já fiz o "teste de mesa" com alguns vetores e ainda não vi a utilidade de `&& i<right` e `&& j>left`. Muito provável que eu não esteja enxergando isso, pois em vários lugares encontrei o quicksort implementado desta maneira com `&& i<right` e `&& j>left`. Se possível, me mostre em que momento neste seu exemplo de `5 4 3 2 1` que é necessário esta implementação.

Comment: Pensando agora, quando o pivo e sempre o elemento do meio acho que nao e relevante mesmo. Mas, se o seu pivo fosse o ultimo elemento do vetor poderia dar problema. Na maioria das implementacoes decentes do quicksort o pivo e escolhido de forma mais ou menos aleatoria, entao e importante por. Nessa que voce colocou, contudo, acho que da na mesma ter ou nao.